# try-catch error "Not covered by Flow"

Tags: flowtype

When I enable the Type Coverage, I get a warning that the error in the catch part of the try-catch is **Not covered by Flow**. If I try to put `catch(err: Error)` I get an **Unexpected token:**

```
try {
// do something that fails and throws an Error
} catch(err) {
  console.error('Error: ', err.message, err.stack)
}
```

So my question is, is it possible to type check it? and if so, what is the best possible solution?

*I'm using FlowType 0.30.0.*

Comment: It may be just a typo in your example, but you are using `err` and `e`, does changing that to one thing help?

Comment: No, i still get an error when setting the `catch(err: Error)` and it is still **Not covered by Flow**.  _have fixed the typo_

Comment: Yeah well the problem is that throwing errors is not covered by flow, as that might be a pretty big undertaking: every function you call may throw an error and bubble into your `catch`, yet you can never be sure if the error you catch is actually an error object... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using Nuclide and have the type coverage feature enabled. You can click the percentage in the status bar to enable/disable it.

The "uncovered" message is not strictly speaking a Flow error. It just informs you that Flow doesn't know the type of something. In this case it's correct. There's no way to know statically what the exception type may be. In JS you can throw any type, so you don't actually know for sure that it's even an error instance.

However it's also a benign message in this case. Personally I don't think that 100% coverage is necessarily a good goal. There are cases where it makes sense to have uncovered code, like this.